# Cross-domain issues between Vue and Django

Tags: django, vue.js, cross-domain

I encountered a problem when using CROS to solve cross-domain issues between Vue and Django. In the Django part, I have completed the corresponding settings and can already request Django from the Vue interface at http://localhost:5173. But when I use http://127.0.0.1:5173 to access Vue, a CORS error occurs when requesting Django.As follows：
[The localhost domain name can be cross-domain normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djPGQ.png)
[A cross-domain error occurred in the 127.0.0.1 domain name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW4tb.png)
My Django side has been configured with corsheaders and CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST
[Django settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruk07.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved!

> The difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1:
>
> localhost: does not transmit through the network card, and is not
> subject to restrictions related to network firewalls and network
> cards.
>
> 127.0.0.1: Transmitted through the network card, dependent on the network card, and subject to restrictions related to the network card
> and firewall.
>
> When accessing localhost, the system takes the current user rights of
> the machine to access. When using IP, it means that the machine is
> accessing the machine through the network, which may involve the
> rights of the network user. Therefore, the general setting program is
> localhost. Localhost will not be resolved into IP and will not occupy
> network cards or network resources.
>
> In addition, I also understand the truth that the general setting
> program is localhost. Localhost will not be resolved into IP and will
> not occupy the network card or network resources.

This blogger configures cross-domain settings in the Django section. Vue partially configures the reverse proxy. In this way, when accessing the Vue project at http://127.0.0.1, the backend data can be requested normally.